# Installing foundationdb k8s operator with helm is failing

Tags: database, foundationdb

I am trying to install fdb k8s operator with helm chart. But when i try to add the repo, getting below error.

```
helm repo add fdb-kubernetes-operator https://foundationdb.github.io/fdb-kubernetes-operator/

Error: looks like "https://foundationdb.github.io/fdb-kubernetes-operator/" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://foundationdb.github.io/fdb-kubernetes-operator/index.yaml : 404 Not Found
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that should be addressed to the maintainers of the foundation db repository, as this command appears as-is in the docs. They should fix it so that the chart is usable.

If you'd like to work around the issue until the issue is remediated, you can clone the GitHub repository itself and install the chart from your local files by running helm install like so -

`helm install fob-operator ./charts/fdb-operator`